# Can't delete data (doc) from Firebase collection when using Redux and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting into React and Redux and after spending a couple of hours on this problem, I'm still not able to delete a doc in Firebase using React and Redux.

I display a project summary in a dashboard and I try to add a delete button.

After the click on the button, the project is passed through to my `projectActions.js` action where I want to delete the project. After this, I want to send the type to the `projectReducer.js`. I don't receive an error and I can't output any `console.log` after the return when I click the button. I do get the project data into the `removeProject()` function.

I've tried to remove the return method in `removeProject()` and `console.log` the project which is passed on. I can get the `project.id` and add this to the `firestore.collection.delete()` function. But since nothing works after the return, this is not possible.

`ProjectSummary.js`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { removeProject } from '../../store/actions/projectActions'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class ProjectSummary extends Component {
  state = {
    project: this.props.project
  }

  handleRemove = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    removeProject(this.state.project)
  }

  render() {
    const { project }  = this.props
    return (
      <div className="card z-depth-0 project-summary">
        <div className="card-content grey-text text-darken-3">
        <Link key={project.id} to={'/project/' + project.id}>
          <span className="card-title">{project.title}</span>
        </Link>
        <p>Posted by {project.authorFirstName} {project.authorLastName}</p>
        <p className="grey-text">{moment(project.createdAt.toDate()).calendar()}</p>
          <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn" onClick={this.handleRemove}>Remove</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>  {
  return {
    removeProject: (project) => dispatch(removeProject(project))
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ProjectSummary)
```

`projectActions.js`:

```js
export const removeProject = (project) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore }) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore()

    firestore.collection('projects').doc(project).delete()
    .then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_PROJECT' })
  }).catch(function(err) {
      dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_PROJECT_ERROR', err})
    });
  }
}
```

`projectReducer.js`:

```js
const projectReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CREATE_PROJECT':
      console.log("Created Project", action.project)
      return state
    case 'CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR':
      console.log('create project error', action.err)
      return state
    case 'REMOVE_PROJECT':
      console.log('Removed Project')
      return state
    case 'REMOVE_PROJECT_ERROR':
      console.log('Removed Project Error', action.err)
      return state

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Your reducer doesn't do anything, it is unclear what it is you are having problems with, it seems you do not understand the concept of redux.

Comment: What do you expect that reducer to do other than print to the console?

Comment: Fairly certain that this is from [The Net Ninja](https://youtu.be/Oi4v5uxTY5o) youtube channel. I'd also be interested to know how to delete posts. Did you manage to find a way?

Comment: Just for clarification, The answer provided below was able to work successfully for The Net Ninja's tutorial.  (with some minor tweaking).

Answer (score 0):

put this on:

ProjectSummary.js

```
    (…)
        import { removeProject } from '../../store/actions/projectActions' 
        import { connect } from 'react-redux';
        (…)
        class ProjectSummary extends Component {
        state = {
          project: this.props.project
        } 
        render() {
        const { project, deleteProject}  = this.props 
        (…) 

            <button onClick={ () => removeProject(project.id)}>Delete</button>

        (…)

            const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
              return {
               removeProject: (id) => { dispatch(removeProject(id))},
              }
             }
        export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ProjectSummary)
```

And 
projectActions.js

```
(…)
export const removeProject = (id) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore }) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore()
    firestore.collection('projects').doc(id).delete();
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you are following The Net Ninja's Tutorial on React-Redux and Firebase, then the general design described above should work for you, with a couple of possible slight adjustments.